# Check checkbox automatically of a htmlform on the basis of spreadsheet cells values

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code witch automatically checks a checkbox on a HTML form when a certain value is found on spreadsheet cell "B2". Now I want to change the code so that it picks up values from a range ex B2:B8 and check multiple checkboxs, how would I do that? for your reference [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZN5UOCpmM_jRrleHVFQU2DpITcN8CEWs7rUNMNOAkRI/edit#gid=0) is the link to my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested I only worked on getting the check boxes check.  The range b2:b8 was larger than required so this code will accept values between 1 and 4 in any of the cells in that range.  The code has already been installed in the shared spreadsheet.

Code.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Add Item');
}

function itemAdd(form) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var match1 = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();

    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1,lastRow).getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<dataRange.length;i++){
        if(dataRange[i][0] == match1){

       if(form["name1"] === "1")
       {
        var delta = "1"
       sheet.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(delta)
       }     


        }
    }

Logger.log(form);

}

function getValues(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var vA=sheet.getRange('B2:B8').getValues();
  return vA;
}
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add Row To Spreadsheet</h1><br />
<form id='myForm'>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="name1" id="name1" value="1"/>Product Landing pages</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="name2" id="name2"/>Missing Attributes</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="name3" id="name3"/>Duplicate Titles</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="name4" id="name4"/>Merchant Promotions</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
    <br><br>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run
              .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
              .itemAdd(this.parentNode)" />
</form>

<script>
$(function() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(checkDefault).getValues();
      });
  function checkDefault(val)
  {
    for(i=0;i<val.length;i++)
    {
      if(val[i]==1  || val[i]==2 || val[i]==3 || val[i]==4)
      {
        var checkBoxName = "name"+val[i];
        document.getElementById(checkBoxName).checked = true;
      }
    }

  }
  console.log('My Code');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh I changed the sheet names.